# Saving and displaying full size photo captured in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to take a photo with the camera and in the activity result method I want to save it and launch a new activity to display the photo from where I saved it, but the imageView stay empty, I used the code [from android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)
and here is my code:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile () throws IOException   {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
       // Bitmap imageBitmap =(Bitmap) extras.get("data");


        Intent formIntent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,FormActivity.class);
       // formIntent.putExtra("img",imageBitmap);
        formIntent.putExtra("path",mCurrentPhotoPath);
        startActivity(formIntent);
    }
}
```

the activity that shoud display the photo

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    File imgFile = new  File(path);
    Toast.makeText(this, path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());


        mImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);


    }
}
```

Comment: `photoFile = createImageFile();`. Do NOT create the file already. You only need a file name. A file path. So create only the name/path.

Comment: `the imageView stay empty`. Because `myBitmap` will be null. Did you check?

Comment: `and in the activity result method I want to save it`. No. You are not doing that. And you do not have to as the camera app will save it to the path you provided in the intent.

Comment: `mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();`. Remove "file:" from it as it will hinder .decodeFile() to do its work.

Comment: Excuse me I'm begginer so could you explain more to me what to do? and why myBitmap will be null?

Comment: Please first check if it is null and then tell us. For the rest: is it that difficult to do the things i proposed?

Comment: I just removed the "file:" and it worked, myBitmap is not null, should I remove "photoFile = createImageFile();"?

Comment: Please reread what i said. You should not create that temp file. But you need the name/path. You can create that File object without creating a (temp)file.

Comment: like this?
private void createImageFile () throws IOException   {
    
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();

}

Comment: If you call `File.createTempFile()` then you are still creating a file. Dont create a file. Only construct a file name/path. And how is it possible that you still add `"file:" ` ???

Comment: I copied it from the old code that's why you find the "file:", I'm still not understanding how to construct the file name/path because I got the code from android developer website and I didn't wrte it

Comment: when I removed "file:" it worked and the app displayed the photo in the imageView but only in the genymotion emulator, when I runned it in my galaxy s5 the new activity comes empty

Comment: You mean: myBitmap is null? Different picture i suppose? What are the resolutions and file sizes?

Comment: no myBitmap is not null I did a test to verify it, where can I find the resolutions and file sizes?

Comment: Files have sizes. Bitmaps have width and height.

Comment: File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);

Comment: I retried to run it in my phone and I used the camera with low quality and it worked

Comment: File image = new File(storageDir, imageFileName); 
Do I replace my code with this?